# Java equivalent of python's struct.unpack?

Tags: java, python, pack

Is there any function equivalent to `struct.unpack('>h', buf)` in java that allows me to unpack values like this?

**SOLUTION**

to unpack data in java we use :  *RandomAccessFile*

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");

    try{
        raf.seek(((i - 1) * 1201 + (j - 1)) * 2);
    }catch(java.io.IOException ex){
        return null;
    }
    byte b1 = raf.readByte();
    byte b2 = raf.readByte();

    byte[]bytes = new byte[] {b1,b2};

    BigInteger swap = new BigInteger(bytes);

    raf.close();
```

Comment: What is `struct.unpack` ?

Comment: Maybe ```Integer.parseInt(buf, 2)``` ?

Comment: If you want to provide an answer to your question, please do so in the answer section below, not as an edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

***">h"*** means short value in big-endian format so that you can just use method [readShort() of DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readShort()) or use 3rd party library like [JBBP](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) and read through its parser (may be you need dynamic string-based format descriptor like provided by Python's struct), in the case it will have something like the snipet

```
 int value = JBBPParser.prepare("short;").parse(fileStream).findFieldForType(JBBPFieldShort.class).getAsInt();
```